Python how to Initiate a Session by Obtaining Visitor GUID and Session ID through Web Scraping
I am successfully obtaining the necessary elements in the Comm100 chat tool, yet I am unable to dynamically retrieve the Visitor GUID and Session ID. Despite my attempts to fetch them from cookies or the payload section, I have not been successful. In my project aiming to open multiple chats in the Comm100 chat tool, randomly generating the Visitor ID is not a suitable solution; hence, I need to proceed with accurate information. When I open the F12 Developer Tools, the network section immediately provides these details upon logging into the site. Unfortunately, I am unable to solve this issue in any way.
I considered using Selenium to accumulate hundreds of Session IDs and Visitor IDs for later use in connections, but I believe this approach may not be effective. I am seeking your assistance.
I  attempted to dynamically retrieve the Visitor GUID and Session ID from cookies and the payload section in the Comm100 chat tool. I expected to successfully obtain this data, but I was unsuccessful. Upon logging into the site, I observed that these details were immediately provided in the network section of the F12 Developer Tools. I considered accumulating hundreds of Session IDs and Visitor IDs using Selenium for future use in connections, but I doubt the effectiveness of this method.
Sample code
import requests
import json
import uuid

# Dinamik sessionId ve diğer değerler
session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
visitor_guid = "c7f498b5-28ce-40fc-9584-d2a22d537219"
campaign_id = "96d56412-ae9a-462a-a01a-5af515da09a5"

url_submit_prechat = f"https://chatserver15.comm100.io/visitor.ashx?siteId=90005058&visitorGuid={visitor_guid}"
url_get_queue_messages = f"https://chatserver15.comm100.io/visitor.ashx?siteId=90005058&visitorGuid={visitor_guid}"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Accept-Language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "https://vue.comm100.com",
    "Referer": "https://vue.comm100.com/"
}

# Pre-chat formunu gönderme
data_prechat = json.dumps([{
    "type": "batchAction",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "submitPrechat",
            "form": {
                "name": "sa",
                "email": "sa@sa.com",
                "company": "test"
            },
            "campaignId": campaign_id,
            "sessionId": session_id
        },
        {
            "type": "requestChat",
            "campaignId": campaign_id,
            "source": {
                "page": {}
            },
            "isPrechatDone": True,
            "isSupportWebrtc": True,
            "lastChattedAgents": ["8f994b25-dd5b-4430-ae15-6ab8f8f078ea"],
            "skipSSO": True,
            "sessionId": session_id
        }
    ],
    "ssoSessionToken": None,
    "id": 5
}])

response_prechat = requests.post(url_submit_prechat, headers=headers, data=data_prechat)

# Yanıtın durum kodunu ve metnini kontrol edelim
print(f"Prechat İsteğinin Status Kodu: {response_prechat.status_code}")
response_text_prechat = response_prechat.text.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
print(f"Prechat Yanıtı (Metin): {response_text_prechat}")

# Yanıtı JSON olarak yüklemeyi deniyoruz
try:
    response_json_prechat = json.loads(response_text_prechat)
    print("JSON Yanıtı Başarıyla Yüklendi:", response_json_prechat)

    chat_guid = response_json_prechat[0]['payload'][1]['payload']['chatGuid']
    print(f"Chat GUID: {chat_guid}")

    # Chat kuyruğunu ve mesajlarını almak
    data_queue = json.dumps([{
        "type": "batchAction",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "getChatQueue",
                "chatGuid": chat_guid,
                "chatVersion": "",
                "sessionId": session_id
            },
            {
                "type": "getChatMessages",
                "chatGuid": chat_guid,
                "fromId": -1,
                "chatVersion": "",
                "sessionId": session_id
            }
        ],
        "ssoSessionToken": None,
        "id": 6
    }])

    response_queue = requests.post(url_get_queue_messages, headers=headers, data=data_queue)
    response_text_queue = response_queue.text.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
    print("Chat Mesajları İsteğinin Status Kodu:", response_queue.status_code)
    print("Chat Mesajları Yanıtı:", response_text_queue)

    # Yanıtın tam yapısını kontrol edelim
    response_json_queue = json.loads(response_text_queue)

    # Tüm yapıyı ekrana bastıralım
    print("Chat Mesajları JSON Yapısı:", json.dumps(response_json_queue, indent=4))

    # messages listesini bulmaya çalışıyoruz
    for action in response_json_queue[0]['payload']:
        if action['type'] == 'getChatMessages':
            messages = action['payload']
            for message in messages:
                sender = message['sender']
                text = message.get('content', '')
                print(f"{sender['type']} ({sender['id']}): {text}")

except KeyError as e:
    print(f"Bir anahtar hatası oluştu: {e}")
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print(f"JSON yanıtı çözümlenirken bir hata oluştu: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Başka bir hata oluştu: {e}")

